# Software app not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-software

My Software app shows 'No Application Data Found' on opening it in Ubuntu 20.04. what should I do?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See if this helps: https://tipsonubuntu.com/2020/04/15/ubuntu-software-no-application-found/